# How to convert gasPrice from ETH Gas Station API to US dollars?

Tags: gas, gas-price

This is a simple call to https://ethgasstation.info/json/ethgasAPI.json

```
{
  "fast": 111,
  "fastest": 180,
  "safeLow": 55,
  "average": 80,
  "block_time": 14.761904761904763,
  "blockNum": 9819011,
  "speed": 0.9302273514361274,
  "safeLowWait": 18,
  "avgWait": 2.8,
  "fastWait": 0.5,
  "fastestWait": 0.5,
  "gasPriceRange": {
    "4": 246,
    "6": 246,
    "8": 246,
    "10": 246,
    "20": 246,
    "30": 246,
    "40": 246,
    "50": 21.4,
    "55": 18,
    "60": 10,
    "70": 7.7,
    "80": 2.8,
    "90": 1.8,
    "100": 0.8,
    "110": 0.6,
    "111": 0.5,
    "120": 0.5,
    "130": 0.5,
    "140": 0.5,
    "150": 0.5,
    "160": 0.5,
    "170": 0.5,
    "180": 0.5
  }
}
```

From the guide I read

> fast: Recommended fast(expected to be mined in < 2 minutes) gas price in x10 Gwei(divite by 10 to convert it to gwei)

This is the param I need, `fast`.

So in this call, `fast` is `111`, so `11.1gwei`.

This is a gas price, right?

My call consume 68988 unit of gas. It's a fixed length hash, so it's every time identical, I hope.

So totale gas paid is 11.1 * 68988 = `765766.8 giga wei`.

Is this calculation right?

How can I determine the money cost of this transaction?

Comment: Do you pass any funds in your transaction (i.e., `value > 0`)?

Comment: No, I simply pass a string, and it is fixed length

Comment: Adjusted the question title as ETH is real money.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa:; you adjustment is WRONG. I am doing a money -> money conversion....

Comment: Just joking :) You made it sound like ETH is not money.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations are correct.

- gasUsed = 68988
- gasPrice = 11.1 gwei
- totalCost = gasUsed x gasPrice = 765,766.8 gwei

Considering that 1 ether is 1,000,000,000 gwei and as of 2020-04-12 22:40 UTC 1 ether = 162 USD, then we have

- 1,000,000,000 gwei are valued 162 USD
- 765,766.8 gwei are valued 162 USD * 765,766.8 gwei / (1,000,000,000 gwei) = 0.1240542216 USD.